# Google Analytics Demo

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to find a web site/resource that has a working demo of Google Analytics to use.

As I have no website etc to be able to link my Analytics account to, I have no way of reviewing/learning to use Google Analytics.

Is anyone aware of such a demo available to the public?

Comment: https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/explorer

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/

Comment: Thank you I shall take a look this evening. Quick question. Do I need to setup the environment with Google API or is there a working version available on line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by environment. If you want a easy setup of using the API use the [Hello Analytics Samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py), The [Demos and tools](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/) site gives examples using both the APIs and data collection samples. But if you are just interested in learning about Google Analytics in general attend the [Analytics Academy](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you're asking for is a site where you can see GA working?

Years ago I set up 3 unusual but extremely effective GA learning sites mainly for myself (so they are crude).

I still use 2 of them today with Real Time reporting and Chrome extensions dataSlayer & WASP.

They accept your own Web Property ID (UA-xxxxx.yy) and save it in a cookie so the data goes into your own account.

1. Captures data to be sent to GA.
   It's currently at http://cyclonal.com.
   It still uses Classic GA (_gaq) - any offers to upgrade it to Universal gladly accepted
2. I also cloned a site used by the GA Dev team's (with permission)
   It tested almost every feature of GA at the time.
   Which is at http://cyclonal.com/g (has a history of the site link in the footer)
3. Finally, and probably what you may want to clone/create yourself, is a free form version of the concepts behind the above sites at http://cyclonal.com/sandbox/codeExec

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google team released a Google Analytics demo account: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en#access                                                          You can start "playing" with this account to get familiarized with google analytics api!